# Work done when decreasing the radius of a rotating object

Tags: work, rotational-kinematics

This is 4.4 in Taylor's classical mechanics textbook.

"A particle of mass $m$ is moving on a frictionless horizontal table and is attached to a massless string, whose other end passes through a hole in the table, where I am holding it. Initially the particle is moving in a circle of radius $r_o$ with angular velocity $\omega_o$, but now I pull the string down through the hole until a length $r$ remains between the hole and the particle."

The question is three parts, one asking for the new angular velocity, one asking to calculate the work done if we pretend the path is a slowly shrinking circle, and one asking to compare the kinetic energy change to the work done.

I have figured out that the new angular momentum $\omega=\frac{r_0^2}{r^2}\omega_0$ by applying conservation of angular momentum, and I have figured out that the change in kinetic energy $\Delta T=\frac{1}{2}m\big(\frac{r_0^4-r_0^2r_f^2}{r_f^2}\big)\omega_0^2$ by using the previous value for the two different kinetic energies and finding the difference. The part I am stuck on is calculating the work. I know that it can be found by integrating torque, however there doesn't seem to be *any* torque, at least as far as I can tell. This would indicate that the work is zero, which disagrees with my $\Delta T$. I'm obviously missing something, but even looking back through the book and online isn't helping.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate the force applied to the end of the string (times) distance the string is retracted to get a W=F*d solution (so no torque calculation required - and note that as angular momentum is conserved there is *no* torque anywhere in the system). Force, at any time, will be equal to the tension in the string.

Excuse lack of math-jax formatting, typing 1-fingered with wrong hand due to recent accident.

Comment: No force is specified though

Comment: @user852541 The force required is exactly m times omega^2 times r (or mv^2/r) - i.e. the instantaneous centripetal force required to cause a body of mass m to rotate in a circle of radius r at angular velocity omega. It is 'specified' by Newton's laws as applied by circular motion.